# Does the normal UK electric meter compensate for voltage fluctuations?

Tags: voltage, current-measurement

Do UK electric meters compensate for voltage fluctuations? Given that it can be 230 V -6%/+10% that gives a fairly wide range.

If I were to run a light bulb at say 100 W would the meter still read accurately over the whole voltage range or would the usage vary at the two extremes?

If it were DC then I know the current would differ, but AC has me flummoxed and as for the meters, I do not know how they do their magic.

Comment: The meter doesn't measure voltage. It measure voltage X amps X time. In other words it measure Watt-hours (as you are well aware that voltage X amps = watts). It doesn't matter how much the voltage fluctuates the meter only measures the power consumption of that light bulb.

Answer (score 14):

Residential electricity meters actually measure the *power* flowing through them.

Back in the days of electromechanical metering (you remember that slowly rotating disk?), that was done by combining one coil that produced a magnetic flux proportional in strength to the current flowing with one coil whose magnetic flux was proportional to the voltage. By having these inherently shifted in phase by 90°, you can get an electromotive force (i.e., an acceleration of a mass) that is proportional to the power drawn "through" the meter. That force turns a disk, which in turn turns a counter.

In the modern days of digital meters, you get a voltage and a current meter, which both are *sampled* several hundred times a second. You then digitally multiply the two measurements to get the drawn power (and integrate the whole fun to get the energy you've consumed). So, same result, different (less expensive, more compact, and easier to deal with) way of achieving the result.

So what happens is that you actually measure power, and pay for it.

Now, a 100 W (incandescent) bulb of course only consumes these 100 W exactly at the nominal voltage – but due to the self-regulating effect of heating resistor wire, the variations below (lower voltage) and above (higher voltage) are going to be much less than what you'd expect. The self-regulation is simple: if the 100 W bulb consumes more power, it gets hotter (that's how it glows!). Now, being hotter increases the resistance of the filament, thereby reducing the current flowing through them, thereby reducing the power. Similar for lower voltages: the filament runs colder, has lower resistance, draws more power, thus runs hotter over time. The thing will stabilize quite well around 100 W, assuming the ability of the bulb to lose heat isn't too high (hang it out in a winter storm, and it might use more than 100W, because the filament can lose heat to the air easily).

Comment: Thanks Marcus, I only used a 100W light bulb as an easy to understand example, It could have been LED as we all like to save the planet or another constant current load. 

I guess the simple answer is YES, the meters know what is happening and we are billed correctly for the usage no matter the voltage supplied at the tails.

Comment: Well put! Exactly, that's what's happening, as a private person, you're getting actually billed for the kWh you *use*, not for the current you draw over time. (The bulb is a nice example nevertheless – a bulb is just a resistor, so it's *apparent* and *effective* powers are the same. An LED lamp contains a switch-mode power supply, where the instant the maximum current flows is not necessarily the one where the highest instantaneous voltage is present. For you, as private user, this makes no difference, because you're being billed for effective power. For industrial users it can be different!)

Comment: Of course the self-regulation of incandescents is only true over quite a limited range, as you'd see if you connected two identical bulbs in series (I suggest doing this at 12VDC with automotive components, but it works just as well with mains)

Comment: @ChrisH sure, that's true, but I'd bet it's relatively good over the specified range.

Comment: @MarcusMüller a few weeks ago I had access to a variable transformer and could have satisfied my curiosity on a mains bulb. Different job now, but testing with LVDC would still be possible

Comment: @ChrisH I'd be kind of surprised if nobody ever tested this and wrote down their results!

Comment: (a low voltage version) would make a good high school or first year undergrad experiment, though from my physics point of view this would be part of an experiment that estimated the filament temperature by fitting the not-quite-black-body spectrum

Answer (score 7):

Induction meters (the spinny-wheel kind) automatically compensate for voltage (with a ‘pressure coil’) as they measure AC current, so they yield an accurate real power measurement even if the voltage fluctuates. More here: https://www.electrical4u.com/induction-type-meters/

Electronic meters measure current and voltage directly, so they compensate for voltage fluctuation using math. More here: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/all-electronic-power-and-energy-meters.html

Mechanical or electronic, what makes this work for AC meters is that instantaneous power at any given moment is the *product* of voltage and current (P = V x I). With a resistive load like your 100W light bulb, the AC voltage and current are *phase-aligned* as they alternate between positive and negative *together*. Their product V x I - that is, power - will always a *positive* quantity. (This is true for *real* power. We’ll touch on reactive power below.)

Watthour meters measure *energy*, the integral of power over time. A mechanical meter does this integration by counting the disc spins, while an electronic meter calculates an average power figure over a specified time and adds that to the tally for kWh (basically, it computes a piecewise integral.)

Let’s discuss real and reactive power for a moment. First, not to worry, household meters measure real power because any reactive currents that result I vs. V phase lead/lag are canceled out by the meter.

How? Think of it this way. Reactive loads like inductors cause I to lag V. There will be times then that I and V will be opposite polarity, which in turn causes their product I x V to have periods of *negative* polarity: there are times where reactive power has a *negative* sign:

[image]

From here: [How can we visualize active reactive and apparent power as areas in time domain?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/427562/how-can-we-visualize-active-reactive-and-apparent-power-as-areas-in-time-domain)

In the meter, these negative-sign reactive power periods *cancel out* the intervals when reactive power I and V are the same sign. The net calculation left over is real power only.

By the same token, if the load is a pure reactance, no power at all is consumed, and the power meter would read zero even through there is current circulating. This corresponds to an I vs. V phase shift of 90 degrees. You get that with AC across just an inductor or a just a capacitor.

Comment: Thanks Hacktastical, I guess the question came about from tinkering with remote display devices where you have to enter the voltage. Obviously they have no direct connection so unlike meters they need that user input. Now I can dedicate the next few years to pondering over my next question.